# Is hydroxyproline an amino acid? (Classification question)

Tags: biochemistry, medicine

So I know that hydroxyproline is created from proline via hydroxylation as a post-translational modification. I also know that proline is considered an amino acid. However, once you hydroxylize it, you have made a covalent modification to the original amino acid. Can hydroxyproline be correctly considered an amino acid? Or is it simply an amino acid derivative and NOT an amino acid?

Or, a more general question - how much can you change an amino acid and still call it an amino acid?

Answer (score 1):

The other commenter answered correctly that proline is an imminoacid, not an amminoacid. But in biochemistry it is referred to as amminoacid since it basically works like every other amminoacid in any polypeptyde.

> how much can you change an amino acid and still call it an amino acid?

Have a look at:

- [Selenocysteine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenocysteine)
- [Ornitine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithine)

As you can see there are some weird modifications of amminoacids in biology. Just like proline/hydroxyproline any amminoacid can be very well modified and be used in proteinogenesis or non-proteinogenesis. Every modification of an amminoacid is allowed, and it will still be considered an amminoacid, even if it doesn't make up a protein. The only parts which can't be changed are the COO- and NH3+ groups, obviosuly, since they give the name of the molecule: "ammino" means that it has a NH group and "acid" means it has a COO- group.